# searchBar overlapped by section header view

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, autolayout, uisearchbar

I put the searchBar inside the tableHeaderView.
Everything works fine on iphone 6 but on iphone 5s I get this weird result?

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.sectionIndexColor = Constants.Colors.ThemeGreen
    tableView.sectionIndexBackgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    tableView.sectionIndexTrackingBackgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0, 0, CGFloat(Constants.Dimensions.TabBarHeight), 0)
    resultSearchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: nil)
    resultSearchController.searchResultsUpdater = self
    resultSearchController.dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation = false
    resultSearchController.definesPresentationContext = true
    tableView.tableHeaderView = resultSearchController.searchBar
    resultSearchController.searchBar.sizeToFit()

 //Fetch data for the first time
    do{
      try fetchedResultsController.performFetch()
      listHeaderView?.count = "\(fetchedResultsController.fetchedObjects!.count)"
    }catch{
      print("Error - Couldn't fetch list")
    }
```

- NOTE: I'm using a NSFetchedResultController to retrieve the data

[image]

Comment: I am still facing this issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the solution.
Don't call sizeToFit() AFTER putting the searchBar in tableHeaderView but call it BEFORE.
What the hell is going on behind the scene... I wonder..

```
resultSearchController.searchBar.sizeToFit() //Important to call sizeToFit BEFORE adding it to tableHeaderView or you get layout issues
tableView.tableHeaderView = resultSearchController.searchBar
```

Comment: even after calling sizeToFit before adding , I am facing this issue ...

Answer (score 0):

It seems only below line of code does work ... nothing else seems to work right now.

```
self.tableView.beginUpdates()
       // self.tableView.setTableHeaderView(headerView: self.filterView!)
        //self.tableView.reloadData()
        self.tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
        self.tableView.layoutSubviews()
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
```

everytime your table resize or change constraints you need to call above code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it may work

`resultSearchController.clipToBounds = true`

You can also try the same as

```
searchControl.searchBar.clipToBounds = true
```

I think it works for your code.