# searchBar overlapped by section header view not answered yet: Need Answer in Swift 3

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

I need an answer in swift 3 not objective c. Thanks.

The issue I am facing is that searchBar overlapped by section header view. The list of items in the table view controller work correctly they scroll behind the search bar its just the headers sections that are overlapping the search bar on scroll up.

I found this post the link is below which is the issue I am facing. However the fixes doesn't work for me.

[searchBar overlapped by section header view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35284605/searchbar-overlapped-by-section-header-view)

The fixes in the above url post doesn't work for me I quote:
"Here is the solution. Don't call sizeToFit() AFTER putting the searchBar in tableHeaderView but call it BEFORE. What the hell is going on behind the scene... I wonder.."

Thanks for your help in advanced.

Teli

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7KIM1.png)
 [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/da40M.png)

Comment: upload your code/images from your interface builder so we can have a look - its difficult to find a solution when we can't see the problem! :]

Comment: Thanks for the feed back I just upload a couple of  images. Thanks again. The number 5 is a header. The others in the list work, however, it's just all the headers that show up in the search bar when you scroll up.

Comment: you have separate search bar and tableView. and you are not using search controller right??

Comment: Exactly. I have not enabled the search controller as of yet. The search bar is written in Swift 3 code and doesn't use storyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I added the following line of code and it pushed the section headers to a zPosition of -1, which put the header sections behind the search bar.

```
sectionView.layer.zPosition = -1
```

This worked for me.

Comment: You should provide a complete answer and improve your question by providing code and context. This is likely to be voted down